# EF 6 how to map correctly when DB has not explicit relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am reasonable new to EF 6,

Little Background Info:
The current DB setup disallows as constraints within the db schema, thus all associations are done in code. In addition we only explicitly load a relation when required, otherwise the reference will be null.

Issue is when I am Mapping Task to Task_Postion
, which I need as a bi - directional association.

```
        public TaskPositionMapping()
        {
            this.ToTable("MIC_Task_Position");
            this.HasKey(p => new { p.TaskId, p.PositionId });            
            this.Property(p => p.TaskId).HasColumnName("NM_TASK");
            this.Property(p => p.PositionId).HasColumnName("NO_POSITION_TYPE_COUNT").HasColumnType("int");
            this.HasMany(p=>p.Tasks).WithRequired(p => p.TaskPosition).HasForeignKey(p=>p.TaskId);
        }
```

,

```
       public TaskMapping()
       {
           this.ToTable("MIC_Task");
           this.HasKey(p => p.TaskId);
           this.Property(p => p.TaskId).HasColumnName("NM_TASK");           
           this.HasMany(p => p.TaskSkills);
            this.HasRequired(p => p.TaskPosition).WithMany(p => p.Tasks).HasForeignKey(p => p.TaskId);
       }
```

,

```
public partial class Task
{
    public Task()
    {        
    }

    public string TaskId { get; set; }     

    [DataMember, IgnoreDataMember()]
    public virtual ICollection<TaskSkill> TaskSkills { get; set; }

    [DataMember, IgnoreDataMember()]
    public virtual TaskPosition TaskPosition { get; set; }

}
```

,

```
public class TaskPosition
    {
        public string  TaskId 
        { 
            get; 
            set;
        }

        public short PositionId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember, IgnoreDataMember()]
        public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    }
```

I get the errors:

- TaskPosition_Tasks_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
  'TaskPosition_Tasks_Target' in relationship 'TaskPosition_Tasks'.
  Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper
  bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.
- TaskPosition_Tasks_Source_TaskPosition_Tasks_Target: : The number of
  properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship
  constraint must be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem identified as the relationship being backwards.

EF 6 does not allow for the above relationship as the Foreign Key signature needs to match the primary key.

Switching the One to Many around allows for a Key - Foreign Key relationship on TaskId

If you need to have the described relationship above, seems you need to handle this manually outside of EF 6 and have separate calls to your repository to populate the data when required.